# Conflict between Google Play Services and HoloEverywhere dependencies on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-support-library, android-holo-everywhere, android-gradle-plugin

I've just started using Android Studio and Gradle and I'm facing a conflict error when I try to run my app. I've already done some research and the problem is that HoloEverywhere uses a custom support-v4 library (some internal classes have its visibility changed) that differs from the support-v4 library used by other libs, in this case Google Play Services. I've read in some posts like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9527075/failed-to-build-android-app-refer-to-both-actionbarsherlock-viewpagertabs-wi) to use the same support-v4 library across all modules, but in this case I can't do it because without the custom support-v4 library, the HoloEverywhere doesn't work and I can't touch the support-v4 library used by Google Play Services. I hope someone has already experienced this and found a solution, because this is driving me nuts :)

**Here is the error log:**

```
Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
    > com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
/Users/diego/Documents/android-sdk-macosx/build-tools/19.0.1/dx --dex --output 
/Users/diego/Documents/WorkspaceAndroid/WorkspaceTest/app/build/libs/app-debug.dex 
/Users/diego/Documents/WorkspaceAndroid/WorkspaceTest/app/build/classes/debug 
/Users/diego/Documents/WorkspaceAndroid/WorkspaceTest/app/build/dependency-cache/debug 
/Users/diego/Documents/WorkspaceAndroid/WorkspaceTest/app/build/pre-dexed/debug/classes-2c9d7b640eaa13481d9d1c220b95094b847d6825.jar 
/Users/diego/Documents/WorkspaceAndroid/WorkspaceTest/app/build/pre-dexed/debug/classes-2edf2d8c7b1a7575431e0269a325d54bdc9fc798.jar 
/Users/diego/Documents/WorkspaceAndroid/WorkspaceTest/app/build/pre-dexed/debug/classes-bc16442b2fdfdfc88911109da1e6baf89a7938a0.jar 
/Users/diego/Documents/WorkspaceAndroid/WorkspaceTest/app/build/pre-dexed/debug/nineoldandroids-2.4.0-1e541581bdb9515af0d791ecbc51193b05f1c93a.jar 
/Users/diego/Documents/WorkspaceAndroid/WorkspaceTest/app/build/pre-dexed/debug/support-v4-13.0.0-2f3822466a4631d8fa7d69b3fd104b27f4df0298.jar 
/Users/diego/Documents/WorkspaceAndroid/WorkspaceTest/app/build/pre-dexed/debug/support-v4-19.0.1-a98845f591723a85fad8ed448a9cc0ced3cb3194.jar 
/Users/diego/Documents/WorkspaceAndroid/WorkspaceTest/app/build/pre-dexed/debug/support-v4-19.0.1a-f1f3d357780dd5b4d33c6ca1830109136769ef22.jar
    Error Code:
    2
    Output:
    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:594) 
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:552)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:533)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:170)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:188)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:439)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:287)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:199)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:103)
```

**settings.gradle:**

```
include ':app'
include 'Volley'
include 'Facebook'
include 'ViewPagerIndicator'
include 'HoloEverywhere'

project(':Volley').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, 'libraries/volley')
project(':Facebook').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, 'libraries/facebook-android-sdk/facebook')
project(':ViewPagerIndicator').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, 'libraries/Android-ViewPagerIndicator/library')
project(':HoloEverywhere').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, 'libraries/HoloEverywhere/library')
```

**build.gradle in the 'app' directory:**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
        mavenCentral()
}

android {
        compileSdkVersion 19
        buildToolsVersion '19.0.1'

        defaultConfig {
                minSdkVersion 10
                targetSdkVersion 19
        }
}

dependencies {
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.0.30'
        compile project(':Volley')
        compile project(':Facebook')
        compile project(':ViewPagerIndicator')
        compile project(':HoloEverywhere')
}
```

**build.gradle in the 'HoloEverywhere/library' directory:**

```
buildscript {
        repositories {
                mavenCentral()
        }
        dependencies {
                classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.+'
        }
}

apply plugin: 'android-library'

dependencies {
        compile files ('libs/support-v4-19.0.1.jar')
        compile files ('libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar')
}

android {
        compileSdkVersion 19
        buildToolsVersion '19.0.1'

        defaultConfig {
                minSdkVersion 7
                targetSdkVersion 19
        }

        sourceSets {
                main {
                    manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
                    java.srcDirs = ['src']
                    res.srcDirs = ['res']
                }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trial and error and thanks to @pyus13 and @Prototik tips, I was able to run my project using Android Studio. I removed all local copies of the dependency libraries, except for the ViewPagerIndicator. Here are the working gradle files:

**settings.gradle:**

```
include ':app'
include 'ViewPagerIndicator'

project(':ViewPagerIndicator').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, 'libraries/Android-ViewPagerIndicator/library')
```

**build.gradle in the 'app' directory:**

```
buildscript {
        repositories {
                mavenCentral()
        }
        dependencies {
                classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.+'
                classpath 'org.holoeverywhere:plugin:0.2.+'
        }
}

apply plugin: 'holoeverywhere'
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
        mavenCentral()
}

holoeverywhere {
        addons {
                create 'preferences'
                create 'slider'
        }
        library {
                version '2.1.0'
        }
}

android {
        compileSdkVersion 19
        buildToolsVersion '19.0.1'

        defaultConfig {
                minSdkVersion 10
                targetSdkVersion 19
        }
}

dependencies {
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.0.30'
        compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.+'
        compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.+@aar'
        compile 'fr.avianey:facebook-android-api:3.6.+@aar'

        compile project(':ViewPagerIndicator')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make these changes required, Please avoid to use local projects if the repository is available on maven :

For volley use :

```
 compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
```

in your app module's build.gradle file and remove all things related to Volley in settings.gradle.

As per the holoeverywhere library here

https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere/blob/master/library/build.gradle

It is using these dependency

```
 dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.+'
   compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0@jar'
 }
```

Download this and add in to your project by replacing what you have already.

If the support dependency is in one the gradle project module like in your case (holoeverywhere or viewpageindicator) do not need to include it in any another module so remove if it has.

After doing doing all these changes sync your project with gradle using this button.

Comment: When I use: compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.1@jar', it cant find the lib classes. Maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: i have copied that from github library check my updated answer and try.

Comment: If i use 'compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.+' it will not find some specific classes from the custom version of the support library. And also it doesn't find 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0@jar'

Comment: Make sure you have download the latest code from github for holoeverywhere only a month ago support library is moved to 19 version and i think you have to use that jar only to make your code working not the one which is in Google repository. Once you download the new code you will find the dependency automatically. Please screenshot of your code structure.